# Failed to create or configure Hyper-V VM: Sequence contains no elements

Tags: docker, docker-compose, visualization, docker-machine, hyper-v

I'm trying to run Docker.

Allways I start Docker I get this error.

I couldn't upload image becouse my reputation is under 10. So images are connected via hypertext links.

Image showing an error from Docker after openning application.

https://ibb.co/rtCYsPp

Log:

```
Docker.Core.HttpBadResponseException:
Failed to create or configure Hyper-V VM: Sequence contains no elements..

One of the most common reasons is virtualization features not working properly, see https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization.
   at Docker.Core.Logging.HttpClientExceptionInterceptor.<InterceptResponseAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Logging\HttpClientExceptionInterceptor.cs:line 17
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.Core.Logging.LoggingMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Logging\LoggingMessageHandler.cs:line 36
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Core.BackendAPI.BackendAPIClient.<CreateHyperVVMAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\BackendAPI\BackendAPIClient.cs:line 92
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.LinuxHyperVEngine.<DoStartAsync>d__14.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\LinuxHyperVEngine.cs:line 59
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 92
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.Engines.Engines.<WaitCurrentTransitionsAsync>d__30.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\Engines.cs:line 358
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.Engines.<RestartAsync>d__26.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\Engines.cs:line 250

  Docker.Core.Backend.BackendQuitException:
  Failed to create or configure Hyper-V VM: Sequence contains no elements..
  
  One of the most common reasons is virtualization features not working properly, see https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization.
     at Docker.Backend.HyperV.<CreateOrConfigureAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperV.cs:line 122
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at Docker.Backend.HttpAPI.HyperVController.<CreateVMAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\stable-2.5.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HttpAPI\HyperVController.cs:line 35
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__0.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
```

Note:

- My visualization is enabled.
- I have Win 10 Pro
- I have downloaded protocol for Hyper V - https://superuser.com/questions/1411967/hyper-v-generic-failure
- I did uninstall Docker (with restart) and then installed it again
- In Hyper V Manager when I try to create new Virtual Machine I always get a "Generic failure" error

Image of Generic error from Hyper-V Manager.

https://ibb.co/xD3GMmy

Comment: For more information I'm facing same problem as described here https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/docker/for-win/7246/662213629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's becouse your Windows 10 build is 18xxx you need to update it to 19xxx. That will fix your problem.